# Marshall Xml file

Tags: java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
  <parents-arg>
    <child>
      <arg>
        <local>
          <method>
            <name>responseData</name>
            <arg>
              <local>
                <method>
                  <name>AAAAAA</name>
                  <local>
                    <boolean>0</boolean>
                  </local>
                </method>
              </local>
            </arg>
          </method>
          <method>
            <name>success</name>
            <local>
              <boolean>1</boolean>
            </local>
          </method>
        </local>
      </arg>
    </child>
  </parents-arg>
</parent>
```

I want to Marshall the above XMl file. But when i am using Jaxb, it is creating a bean class with more than one staic class named as local. So how can i marshall the above xml.
I used the following command to marshall the `xml xjc -extension -p parser Marshall.xsd` (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)

Comment: did you get any errors while marshalling?? also why your xml has multiple local tags at different hierarchial level, i think that is not valid.

Comment: My XML will be like this only. While creating a bean class using the abouve command, i dont get any error. It creates a bean class with more than one static class named as local.

Comment: no, i am asking did you tried marshalling it i.e. converting your xml to object ? If ye, did you get any errors?

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to "marshall" or "unmarshall" this xml structure (see explanation at your link to the Oracle page). Should you want to marshall it everything depends on your Marshall.xsd file, which you should post here.